# Static field not being recognized as persistable by Realm Java

Tags: java, android, realm

Realm is giving me an error complaining that my class "must have at least 1 persistable field". This class has 1 static field to store a preferences option in my app, and some other static methods.

Shortened Code:

```
public class StreamingPreferences extends RealmObject {
     public static RealmList<RealmString> serviceStreamingPreferences;
}
```

Realm [appears to support static fields](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/pull/934) and my custom RealmString class extends RealmObject, as does RealmList. I'm completely new to Realm and this is the only part of my model that I can't get to work without adding some non static field. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure the version of Realm you're using supports static fields?

Comment: Yes, I am using version 1.1

Comment: What does realmstring look like

Comment: This seems to be a bug in Realm's categorizeClassElements() function from class ClassMetaData. You should get in touch with someone from Team Realm or raise an issue in Realm's GitHub. For time being you can solve this issue by adding one more field in your StreamingPreferences class which is of primitive type. e.g. private int tempField;

Comment: Thank you Viraj, I raised an [issue](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/3205) and passed on your guess.

Comment: Great, I saw the response from Gabor Varadi "Zhuinden" on the issue you have reported on Realm-java and it makes things a lot clearer. I will try to summarise it in an answer so that it might be beneficial for other people having same issue.

Comment: @immibis they're supported in the sense that they're "allowed". Only instance fields are persisted, though.

Answer (score 1):

Static fields are supported in the sense that they're allowed in the `RealmObject`'s class.

They're automatically ignored, they're not persisted.

It is as specified in [this comment](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/3205#issuecomment-234704313).

Answer (score 0):

**Error message** - "must contain at least 1 persistable field"

**Root cause** - Using ONLY static field(s) in your RealmObject class

**Reason** - Realm allows us to have static fields in RealmObject class, but since static fields do not belong to an instance of the Class (they belong to the Class), static field(s) has the same copy across all the instances of given Class. Since Realm ignores all static fields, it does not accept a RealmObject which ONLY has static field(s), we must put at-least one non-static field ALONG with one or more static filed(s).

**History** - As discussed here https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/464, Realm used to process static fields as part of the RealmObject, but after the discussion team Realm agreed to ignore all static field(s).

This is allowed

```
public class Test extends RealmObject {
    /* One non static filed */
    private int test1;
    /* One or more static filed(s) */
    public static int test2;
}
```

This is not allowed

```
public class Test extends RealmObject {
    /* Only static field(s) */
    public static int test1;
}
```